# Returns values of functions Python Multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I'm trying to generate the checksum of two identical files (in two different directories) and am using multiprocessing.Process() to run the checksum of both files simultaneously instead of sequentially.

However, when I run the multiprocessing.Process() object on the checksum generating function I get this return value:

```
<Process(Process-1, stopped)> 
<Process(Process-2, stopped)>
```

These should be a list of checksum strings.

The return statement from the generating function is:

```
return chksum_list
```

Pretty basic and the program works well when running sequentially.

How do I retrieve the return value of the function that is being processed through the multiprocessing.Process() object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) are relatively good on this topic;

**Pipes**

You could communicate via a pipe to the process objects;

From the docs:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def f(conn):
    conn.send([42, None, 'hello'])
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    print parent_conn.recv()   # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

**Pool & map**

Alternatively you could use a `Pool` of processes:

```
pool = Pool(processes=4) 
returnvals = pool.map(f, range(10))
```

where `f` is your function, which will act on each member of `range(10)`.
Similarly, you can pass in any list containing the inputs to your processes;

```
returnvals = pool.map(f, [input_to_process_1, input_to_process_2])
```

In your specific case, `input_to_process_1/2` could be paths to the files you're doing checksums on, while `f` is your checksum function.

Comment: Yes I've been reviewing the documents but was unable to find any information about getting the return value from the function that is being processed in the Process object.

I'm trying to assign the return value (a list of strings) from that function to a variable. That will then be iterated over to complete another task within the main function.

Thanks for your help so far.